# Обернуть выражение php в div или span

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте!
Есть код -

```
<?
    if (!empty($arItem['MIN_PRICE']))
    {
        if ('N' == $arParams['PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE'] && isset($arItem['OFFERS']) && !empty($arItem['OFFERS']))
        {

            echo GetMessage(
                'CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_PRICE_SIMPLE_MODE',
                array(
                    '#PRICE#' => $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE'],
                    '#MEASURE#' => GetMessage(
                        'CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_MEASURE_SIMPLE_MODE',
                        array(
                            '#VALUE#' => $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['CATALOG_MEASURE_RATIO'],
                            '#UNIT#' => $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['CATALOG_MEASURE_NAME']
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

        }
        else
        {
            echo $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE'];
        }
        if ('Y' == $arParams['SHOW_OLD_PRICE'] && $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['DISCOUNT_VALUE'] < $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['VALUE'])
        {
            ?> <div class="single-item-price OLD"><span><? echo $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['PRINT_VALUE']; ?></span></div><?
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Как обернуть в `div` или `span` только вот это выражение -

```
'#PRICE#' => $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE']
```

Answer (score 1):

Не гарантирую, но попробуй:

```
'#PRICE#' => '<span>' . $arItem['MIN_PRICE']['PRINT_DISCOUNT_VALUE'] . '</span>'
```

Comment: А лучше добавь к своему вопросу метку #bitrix — нужный спец быстрей найдется